# Can I make a form to go to a user specified URL?

Tags: html, css, forms, iframe, form-submit

I am new to these fourms and I have a (hopefully) small question to ask...except that I haven't found the answer anywhere... :(

I want to make a html (no Javascript, Yes CSS) form that will ask the user for a URL, and then send them to it. I also want this to work in an iFrame. I understand some links, however, will not open in the iFrame (example google.com: Google won't open in iFrame).

Is there any way to do this? So far this is my code (inside the iframe):

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>URL</title>
</head>

<body>
<form>
  <input type="url" placeholder="http://" required>
  <input type="submit" value="Go" formtarget="_self">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

But I don't know how to make the "GO" button work... :(

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: ru asking about a client side redirect? the `wondow.location.href = value` should work

Comment: I don't think that without Javascript or jQuery (on client side) it is possible. I think that you need some client side scripting language or some server side language to deal with requirement you have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*"I want to make a html (no Javascript, Yes CSS)"*
I can tell you this much what ever you want to achieve with this form, you wont be able to achieve it with CSS. The easiest would be to do it with jquery.